# Do you need to include all foreing keys of a parent table in the child table?

Tags: foreign-key

Suppose you have a table

```
my_table
-----------
id
name
foreign_id
```

And you are creating another table that will reference my_table. I think that this would be enough:

```
other_table
-----------
id
name
my_table_id
```

However, when creating a diagram on MySQL workbench, if I create a relationship, whether identifying or non-identifying, 1 to 1, or 1 to many, I get this table:

```
other_table
-----------
id
name
my_table_id
foreign_id
```

As you can see, both, the id of my_table, and the foreign_key of my_table get added to the new table. Is that really necessary? I would say that `other_table.foreign_id` is not necessary.

I first noticed this when I was working on schemabank.com (which seems to be gone now, such a shame). And now I noticed it too on MySQL workbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I follow but here's an example using more meaningful names:

Given these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
 person_ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Employees 
(
 employee_ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
 person_ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
 FOREIGN KEY (person_ID)
    REFERENCES Persons (person_ID), 
);
```

I think you are saying you would add a referencing table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE HourlyPaidEmployees
(
 employee_ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
 FOREIGN KEY (employee_ID)
    REFERENCES Employees (employee_ID) 
);
```

I would be inclined to agree because I am a human who can understand that given two candidate keys I will choose `employee_ID` because the table name `HourlyPaidEmployees` strongly suggests it pertains to employees.

However, it seems your software generates this:

```
CREATE TABLE HourlyPaidEmployees
(
 employee_ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
 FOREIGN KEY (employee_ID)
    REFERENCES Employees (employee_ID),
 person_ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
 FOREIGN KEY (person_ID)
    REFERENCES Employees (person_ID) 
);
```

I would guess that the software has been designed so that given two candidate keys it should not attempt to 'guess' which one to use and therefore uses both and leaves it to the user to decide which one to remove.

Comment: Thanks, I always used only one foreign key, but then I saw that a few weeks ago, when I used schemabank, and I was wondering about it. I thought that was some kind of unspoken rule.